# how to use 2 mic in android ics 4.0.3

Tags: android, c, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, linux-device-driver

I am working on AM3715 based custom designed board with Android ics 4.0.3.In the board there are 2 mic ,headset works fine,but onboard mic not works...I want to change the headset configuration for onboard mic .I changed signals in /sound/soc/codec/twl4030.c  ,REG_ANAMIC as 0x01 for sub mic and commented headset register REG_ANAMICL .But after recording no sound from microphone...can any one help??

Comment: Hey Got any solution for this? Enabling to mics?  is it possible from arduino?